# query cat orderby and order not working

Tags: categories

I am using wp 4.94 for web library. In the categories sections I give the option to the users to order the posts in three different ways, by date, by title and by author, ascending and descending. However, only sort by date works. This is implemented through links

```
echo '<p align="center">Ordenar por titulo: &nbsp;</p>';
                echo '<p align="center">';
                echo '<a href="' . get_option('home') . '/?cat=' . $category->cat_ID . '/?orderby=title&order=asc"><b>Ascendente</b></a>';
                echo '&nbsp;/&nbsp;';
                echo '<a href="' . get_option('home') . '/?cat=' . $category->cat_ID . '/?orderby=title&order=desc"><b>Descendente</b></a>';
echo '</p>';
```

The link is like this.

```
http://localhost/blog/?cat=25/?orderby=title&order=asc
```

Sort by title alphabetically and by author, do not work. why? it's a clean installation, no plugins or anything installed

Comment: how do you set the `$category` variable? you might have the wrong syntax in your code; compare with: `echo '<a href="' . get_option('home') . '/?cat=' . $category->cat_ID . '&orderby=title&order=asc"><b>Ascendente</b></a>';`

Comment: through if (is_category() { echo... }

Comment: Ok. Very good. Function!! changed '?' by '&' thanks